# Creating cloud sql tables from Dataflow job

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-sql

There is a pipeline that will copy table data from BigQuery to CloudSql.

Cloud SQL table creation was happening outside dataflow.

Now we need to have the table creation in Dataflow.

I have the tables to be created in GCS bucket as .sql file.

Below is the code snippet which copies table from BQ to sql.

```
        p.apply(BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
                    .from(source_table)
                    .withTemplateCompatibility()
                    .withoutValidation())
           
            .apply(JdbcIO.<TableRow>write()
                    .withDataSourceConfiguration(
                            JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(
                                    "org.postgresql.Driver",
                                    base_url
                            )
                    )
                    .withStatement("INSERT INTO " + target_table.split("\\.")[1] + " VALUES " + insert_query)
                    .withPreparedStatementSetter(new StatementSetter(some_map)));
    p.run();
```

Is there a way I can execute the .sql file using JDBCIO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JdbcIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.html) in Apache Beam can only be used to read from and write to JDBC datasources. Unfortunately, a `.sql` file cannot be executed using JdbcIO. Because, JdbcIO requires the databases and tables to be created before writing data into them. The same applies to DDL commands like `CREATE`.

A workaround to automate the table creation would be to use [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build) with Dataflow. The end-to-end process could be created as a Cloud Build job that creates the Table by using the cloud client, and then the Dataflow job could be triggered. Please refer to this [Medium article](https://medium.com/@zhongchen/dataflow-ci-cd-with-cloudbuild-1ad503c1c81) for a sample Cloud Build-Dataflow setup.

If this feature is an important element in your pipeline, please raise a feature request with the Apache Beam team on [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/BEAM/issues/) under the Beam project. To do so, JIRA requires a sign-in.